# How to save and display User IP and location with django and GeoIP2

Tags: python, django, jinja2

**This has been answered!**

I am trying to display the client ip address upon login if the user is the Admin. However, I am unable to display the 'ip' variable in the home.html template. I have a function in views.py that returns the desired variable. **How can I call this function upon loading of the home.html page? There are no errors.**

home.html

```html
    {% if user.is_staff %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin Panel</a></p>
        <p>{{ ip }}</p>
    {% else %}
        Hello {{ user.username }}
        <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
     {% endif %}
```

views.py

```py
    def get_client_ip(request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
            return render_to_response('home.html', {"ip": ip})
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            return render_to_response('home.html', {"ip": ip})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), # sign up
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # authenticate
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), 
]
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),

]
```

I expect to display the 'ip' variable in my home.html template.

Comment: try `render_to_response('home.html', ip=ip)`.

Comment: that does not work.

Comment: use `print(ip)` in view to check if you have any value in `ip`.

Comment: in the get_client_ip() function you mean?

Comment: check **ip** does not have any value

Comment: yes in `get_client_ip()` .

Comment: BTW: do you see `Admin Panel` on your page ? `IP` should be displayed only in `Admin Panel` when `user.is_staff` is true.

Comment: Yes, I see Admin Panel. I believe my ip variable is empty.

Comment: @pranjal0819 what do you suspect is causing this?

Comment: Where you run this code on the hosted server or local server

Comment: Show your urls.py.

Comment: display value on screen or write in file to see what you have in variable.

Comment: I have nothing in variable. I have removed everything and am now just trying to `print('hello') `and there is still nothing. It seems `get_client_ip()` is not being called. Please see my edit.

Comment: @DanielRoseman see my edit

Comment: But none of those URLs are pointing at `get_client_ip`. Which URL are you going to? How are you expecting this to work?

Comment: I am not sure how to point to my get_client_ip from my urlpatterns.

Comment: @DanielRoseman on my home.html page I see /accounts/ instead of the ip variable.

Comment: If you want it to appear on the home page, you need to pass out from the view that renders the home page. Alternatively, use a template tag or context processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I had to update my urls.py to return the view function get_client_ip before the Template was viewed.:**

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), # sign up
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # authenticate
        path('', views.get_client_ip, name='ipaddress'), 
        path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    ]
```

**I also had to update the view itself:**

def get_client_ip(request):
    g = GeoIP2()
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for
        city = g.city(ip)
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        city = g.city(ip)

```
context = {
    'ip': ip,
    'message': message,
     'city': city,
    }

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**My templates.html now looks like so--it takes the context variables from my views function get_client_ip.:**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hello {{ user.username }}
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin Panel</a></p>
    <p>{{ ip }}</p>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <p>{{ city }}</p>

  {% else %}
    <p>{{ ip }}</p>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <p>{{ city }}</p>


  {% endif %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You use the context variable to pass an object from your view to your template

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    context = {
        'IP': ip,
    }     
    return render_to_response('home.html', context)
```

IP variable will now be usable in your html file.

Comment: @Alex I had an extra return statement. Can you please check now. Also please note that IP will be capital in ur html file.

Comment: Ah thats a different problem then.

Comment: @Moeed Your 'IP' in context dictionary is in uppercase and the OP is using lowercase in his template. I think replacing IP with ip in your context dictionary should do the trick!

Comment: i already did this with lowercase in my testing, did not work

Comment: Are you able to log the ip variable in your python console (Are you sure 'ip' variable is not a blank string?). Also can you try printing ip variable outside your if statement in the template? 
One more thing: render_to_response() is deprecated since version 2.0.

Comment: i believe my `get_client_ip()` function is not being called. I have tried placing a simple print statement in it only, and it did not print anything.